# re not matching when using an OR

Tags: python, regex, expression

I am trying to match dates (number in this case) from the following string:

```
mystring = '_20180701_20190630'
```

I am using the following code:

```
re.findall(r'(?:\A|_){1}([0-9]{4}[_]{0,1}[0-9]{2}[_]{0,1}[0-9]{2})(?:$|_){1}', mystring)
```

The pattern that I am looking for is overcomplicated for this very example because I need to take into account also other more complex situations.

Given that, I do not understand why the pattern above does not match the last number, while the following one does (the only difference is the end last characters: **(?:$){1}** vs **(?:$|_){1}** ):

```
re.findall(r'(?:\A|_){1}([0-9]{4}[_]{0,1}[0-9]{2}[_]{0,1}[0-9]{2})(?:$){1}', mystring)
```

Why does OR operator prevent the match? Is it because it is greedy and there is another number before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is actually matching and consuming trailing `_` which is failing next match that must start with `_`.

You may use lookahead to solve this:

```
(?:\A|_)(\d{4}_?\d{2}_?\d{2})(?=_|\Z)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/P1ju2G/1)

By using a positive lookaead i.e. `(?=_|\Z)`, we are only asserting presence of `_` or `\Z` but not really matching it.

I have also refactored your regex to simplify. `{1}` can be removed and `{0.1}` can be replaced with just `?` (optional match). Similarly `[_]` can be just `_` while `[0-9]` can be shortened to `\d`.

Answer (score 0):

In the target sample `_20180701_20190630` there is no match of the beginning of string
`\A`. Why is it offered in the alternation `(?:\A|_)` ?

Can the number possibly have no preceding `_` if at the beginning of string ?

Basically, if this is not a Multi-line operation, the regex should be this :

`(?<![^_])(\d\d\d\d(?:_?\d\d){2})(?![^_])`

https://regex101.com/r/HkGZEo/1
https://regex101.com/r/PkwEdK/1
https://regex101.com/r/VAREFJ/1

for boundary consistency, and drop the anchors entirely.

Expanded

```
 (?<! [^_] )                   # Look Behind, a _ or BOS
 (                             # (1 start)
      \d\d\d\d 
      (?: _? \d\d ){2}
 )                             # (1 end)
 (?! [^_] )                    # Look Ahead, a _ or EOS
```